# Why does SceneKit spotlight angle affect shadow?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, shadow

I'm trying to use a spotlight in my scene and add shadows to an object. However, I noticed that when I increase the `spotInnerAngle`, the shadow of the object changes significantly. Here's an example:

[image]

Both of shadows in these images look quite different – does anyone know why increasing the spot angle is causing the shadow to be less apparent?

This is the code I'm using to create a spotlight/add shadows to my scene:

```
    let spotLight = SCNNode()
    spotLight.light = SCNLight()
    spotLight.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.spot
    spotLight.light?.spotInnerAngle = 120
    spotLight.light?.spotOuterAngle = 120
    spotLight.light?.color = UIColor.white
    spotLight.light?.castsShadow = true
    spotLight.light?.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
    spotLight.light?.shadowSampleCount = 32
    spotLight.light?.shadowRadius = 8
    spotLight.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
    spotLight.light?.shadowMapSize = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2048)
    spotLight.light?.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)
    spotLight.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 5,z: 0)
    spotLight.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi / 2, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit's engine calculates shadows slightly differently than 3D software apps do, like Maya or 3dsMax. In SceneKit framework the `position` and `scale` of your Spotlight as well as its value of `cone angle` are crucial for shadow generating. The main rule is the following: when area of spotlight's ray in SceneKit becomes greater, the shadow edges become more obscure (aka blurry).

Here's a properties you have to take into consideration when using spotlight:

```
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light!.type = .spot
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1)
lightNode.castsShadow = true

/* THESE SEVEN SPOTLIGHT PROPERTIES AFFECT SHADOW'S APPEARANCE */
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 10, 0)
lightNode.scale = SCNVector3(7, 7, 7)
lightNode.light?.spotOuterAngle = 120
lightNode.light?.shadowRadius = 10
lightNode.light?.zNear = 0
lightNode.light?.zFar = 1000000
lightNode.light?.shadowSampleCount = 20

lightNode.light?.shadowColor = UIColor(write: 0, alpha: 0.75)
lightNode.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
```

**Also, I recommend you use `Ambient Light` with very low `Intensity` for lighting up dark areas on your 3D models**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation: 
"[spotInnerAngle] determines the width of the fully illuminated area."

The default value of this property is 0, which means only the center of the area illuminated by the spotlight is lit at full intensity.

Increasing the inner angle will increase the area that is lit at full intensity, thus adding more light to the scene. In your case, this additional light was decreasing the visible shadow from that angle.